# Let $V$ be a normed vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, is there an inner product structure on $V$ such that the two spaces have the same topology.

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $V$ be a complete normed vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $\tau_1$ be the topology induced by its norm. Is there an inner product structure on $V$ such that the topology induced by the norm of the inner product is the same as $\tau_1$ ?

I suspect the answer is no. A sufficent condition for that to happen is that the [parallelogram law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law) holds. Is there a  weaker known sufficient condition ?

Thank you

Comment: No, it's equivalent.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Where can I see a proof ?

Comment: Rough sketch: if a norm is induced by an inner product it fulfills the parallelogram identity. If a norm fulfills the identity, then there is only one inner product from where the norm is induced by construction of that inner product from the norm by polarization.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Firstly thanks for your help. Either I misunderstood your argument or you misunderstood my question. I think the last comment you put is an answer to one of my older questions not to this one. The older question is here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528864/is-every-normed-vector-space-an-inner-product-space  Agree ?

Comment: @Amr It seems that you question is closely related to the discussion at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540302/the-norm-is-not-equivalent-to-another-one-induced-by-some-inner-product

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thank you

Comment: Not only it is related but I would say that this question is identical to the one linked by Alex Ravsky.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Characterizations of Hilbert space among Banach spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#Characterizations_of_Hilbert_space_among_Banach_spaces)